# Why is my bool function not working Xcode

Tags: objective-c

Basically I am trying to get nslog to say on and off in console. But I seem unable to get it functioning correctly. The `NSUserDefaults` works great, but the `NSLog` isn't appearing at all.

**viewcontroller 1 .h**

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISwitch *cameraSwitch;
```

**viewcontroller 1.m**

```
- (void)cameraEnabled
{
    if (cameraSwitch.isOn)
    { 
    }
    else
    {       
    }
}
```

**View controller 2.h**

```
 viewcontroller1 *myVC;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet viewcontroller *myVC;
```

**view controller 2.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UISwitch *onOffSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    /* If it is the first time were are running this code, we will get nil from
       NSUserDefaults, and we'll turn the switch off.
       After the user has set the switch, it will store the value in NSUserDefaults
       and we can remember what to set it to the next time viewDidLoad is called.
    */
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchKey"]) {
        [onOffSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];
    } else {
        [onOffSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];
    }

    [self.myVC.cameraSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(openswitch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)openswitch
{ 
    if (self.myVC.cameraSwitch.isOn)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SwitchKey"];
        NSLog(@"on");  
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"SwitchKey"];
         NSLog(@"off"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever set `self.myVC.cameraSwitch` to anything? E.g. put `self.myVC.cameraSwitch = onOffSwitch;` in viewDidload, or even don't create the new variable `onOffSwitch`, just instantiate `cameraSwitch`.

Comment: Not part of your problem, but if you are accessing properties using dot syntax, you should be using the property name, not the getter name: `if (cameraSwitch.on)` instead of `if (cameraSwitch.isOn)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have set cameraSwitch with an IBOutlet and then you are initializing a newSwith in viewDidLoad:. If you have connected the IBOutlet correctly in xib. You need the following changes

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //No need to initialize switch again
    //UISwitch *onOffSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    /* If it is the first time were are running this code, we will get nil from
       NSUserDefaults, and we'll turn the switch off.
       After the user has set the switch, it will store the value in NSUserDefaults
       and we can remember what to set it to the next time viewDidLoad is called.
    */

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL switchState = [defaults boolForKey:@"SwitchKey"];
    [self.cameraSwitch setOn:switchState animated:NO];

    [self.cameraSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(openswitch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)openswitch
{ 

    BOOL switchState = self.cameraSwitch.isOn;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:switchState forKey:@"SwitchKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSLog(@"Camera Swith State : %@",switchState?@"ON":@"OFF");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like UISwitch (cameraSwitch) is being added via Interface designer as well as through code (onOffSwitch). Try to use any one mechanism for your code to work. Example for adding UISwitch using code that prints NSLog message depending on Switch

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UISwitch *onOffSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    /* If it is the first time were are running this code, we will get nil from
     NSUserDefaults, and we'll turn the switch off.
     After the user has set the switch, it will store the value in NSUserDefaults
     and we can remember what to set it to the next time viewDidLoad is called.
     */
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchKey"]) {
        [onOffSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];
    } else {
        [onOffSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];
    }
    [onOffSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(openswitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:onOffSwitch];

}

-(IBAction)openswitch:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *onOffSwitch = (UISwitch *) sender;
    if (onOffSwitch.isOn)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SwitchKey"];
        NSLog(@"on");
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"SwitchKey"];
        NSLog(@"off");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.